# GWT Internet Explorer ListBox issues (dropdown items are chopped)

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT Dropdown listbox, which on a dropdown expands the dropdown list automatically to show long list items in FF and Chrome. IE however does not resize dynamically as a result the dropdown list shows chopped items.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way

```
    listBox.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
        {
            listBox.addStyleName("expand");
        }
    });

    listBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event)
        {
            listBox.removeStyleName("expand");
            listBox.addStyleName("normal");
        }
    });
    listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
        {
            listBox.removeStyleName("expand");
            listBox.addStyleName("normal");
        }
    });

.normal
{
width=200px;
}

.expand > option
{
width : auto;
}
```

In simple words set width to auto when viewing options else set it to default.

Comment: Hi..I don't want the listbox to expand, only the dropdown needs to be expanded. If the listbox expands it spoils the screen design.

Comment: well in that case you need to modify the class only for onMouseDown and instead of .expand use .expand > option, i will do the edits

Comment: its Internet Explorer 8 [IE 8]